# Two attempts to get to point-free. One of them gets me stuck. Is this normal?

Tags: haskell

I want to make the function

```
addAndDrop x y = x + 1
```

point-free. I start with this obviously:

```
addAndDrop x y = (+1) x
```

But from here there are two different paths I can take.

```
--First path:
addAndDrop x y = const ((+1) x) y
addAndDrop x = const ((+1) x)
addAndDrop x = (const . (+1)) x
addAndDrop = const . (+1) --I'm done!

--Second path:
addAndDrop x y = (+1) (const x y)
addAndDrop x y = ((+1) . (const x)) y
addAndDrop x = (+1) . (const x) --Here I'm stuck!
```

In the first path everything goes smoothly. But in the second path I get stuck.

Is there a way to continue and finish the second path or am I really stuck as I think I am?

And if I really am stuck, is there any fundamental fancy, mathematical/functional/whatever reason for why I get stuck in one path and not in the other path?

Comment: You're not stuck.  There is an algorithm that tells you exactly how to proceed.  Google "bracket abstraction".

Comment: @Michael, sometimes (not this time) rewriting things point-free can lead to some sort of insight into a deeper structure. Sometimes (not this time) rewriting something point-free can allow it to be implemented using `#.` and/or `.#` from `Data.Profunctor.Unsafe`, which sometimes has substantial efficiency advantages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
--Second path:
addAndDrop x y = (+1) (const x y)
addAndDrop x y = ((+1) . (const x)) y
addAndDrop x = (+1) . (const x) --Here I'm stuck!
addAndDrop x = ((+1) .) (const x)
addAndDrop x = (((+1) .) . const) x
addAndDrop = ((+1) .) . const
```

In general, the pattern is that `\x -> f . (g x)` becomes `(f .) . g`